# Early Papers and Books on Math Logic

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, ho.history-overview

I would like to go back to the beginnings of math logic and read selected papers throughout the years connecting the beginnings to today.  My first stop was Wikipedia where it claims that math logic basically begins with De Morgan and Boole.  I have gotten Boole's "The Mathematical Analysis of Logic" to read.  It seems De Morgan's book is either expensive on Amazon or is a scan of an old enough edition that I can't read it.

I have three questions:  First, can I ignore De Morgan as a starting place?  Second, should I be looking into anyone earlier or contemporary to Boole? Third, though my main is to study the development of mathematical logic, I would also like to learn the philosophical traditions a little bit. Is there anything that would be good to read that maybe isn't quite mathematical in nature?

Comment: This question is better suited for history of science forum or math.stackexchange.  Beginning courses in logic usually start with Aristotle or earlier.  If you want a history of algebraic logic, you would do worse than to consult references like the Handbook of Mathematical Logic, which should have other references that cover the early history.  If you are looking for elementary treatments, you might enjoy Lewis Carroll's Game of Logic. Gerhard "Or A Similarly Named Title" Oarsman, 2016.10.13.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman "Algebraic logic" is a technical term, it seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Are you thinking of "symbolic logic"?

Comment: It may seem irrelevant. However, a fair amount of work by DeMorgan and Boole resulted in algebraic structures used to model logical reasoning.  It may be that the poster is interested in that aspect of development of mathematical logic, in which case early texts on universal algebra and the algebraization of logic might be preferred to, say , development of proof theory. @Nate, Symbolic Logic may also be a good read for the poster, in addition to Game of Logic.  Gerhard "Many Like To Play Games" Paseman, 2016.10.13.

Comment: Incidentally, I strongly recommend the many-volume (eleven?) [Handbook of the History of Logic](https://www.elsevier.com/books/book-series/handbook-of-the-history-of-logic).

Comment: There are several anthologies of key original papers: *From Frege to Gödel* and two volumes of *From Kant to Hilbert*, and *From Brouwer to Hilbert* also. It can be challenging to read the original sources, however, due to archaic or idiosyncratic terminology, the difference between the modern perspective and the author's perspective, etc.

Comment: Two secondary sources are worth consulting: Kneale and Kneale's _The Development of Logic_ (Oxford: Clarendon-Oxford University Press, 1962) and Grattan-Guinness's _The Search for Mathematical Roots, 1870-1940: Logics, Set Theories and the Foundations of Mathematics from Cantor through Russell to Gödel_ (Princeton, New Jersey: Princeton University Press, 2000). Both contain helpful pointers to primary texts.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I haven't access to the Handbook of Logic.  But, thank you for suggesting it.  Something along those lines is a good starting place.  Also, Lewis Carroll's book, while not what I am looking for, is something I might use as a leisure reading book.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The Handbook of the History of Logic looks amazing!  I will see if my library can get it.  Spending hundreds (thousands) of dollars is a little out of my price range.

Comment: @CarlMummert I have purchased From Frege to Godel, and am requesting the others from my library.  Good recommendations.

Comment: @grshutt I will look into these.  They seem to be the kind of thing I am looking for to start my journey.

Comment: I would also like to note that half way the 20th century the idea of logic started to shift a little bit and computability started to become more important. A related question is whether the history gives more insight in the theory. For most sciences it doesn't. Physics before Newton will not help you to understand physics, it will only confuse you. Mathematics is an exception, because a mathematical stays valid. For logic, it might be the case that early thoughts are only confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the references mentioned in the comments collectively answer the question, so I'm compiling them into an actual (community wiki) answer so that the system recognizes that the question has been answered.

1. [Handbook of the History of Logic](https://www.elsevier.com/books/book-series/handbook-of-the-history-of-logic).
2. There are several anthologies of key original papers: *From Frege to Gödel* and two volumes of *From Kant to Hilbert*, and *From Brouwer to Hilbert* also.
3. Two secondary sources are worth consulting: Kneale and Kneale's *The Development of Logic* (Oxford: Clarendon-Oxford University Press, 1962) and Grattan-Guinness's *The Search for Mathematical Roots, 1870-1940: Logics, Set Theories and the Foundations of Mathematics from Cantor through Russell to Gödel* (Princeton, New Jersey: Princeton University Press, 2000). Both contain helpful pointers to primary texts.
4. You would do worse than to consult references like the *Handbook of Mathematical Logic*, which should have other references that cover the early history. If you are looking for elementary treatments, you might enjoy Lewis Carroll's *Game of Logic*.  *Symbolic Logic* may also be a good read.